# Array of pointers like (*(volatile unsigned long *)0x40004000)

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I am having a very hard time figuring out how to solve the following problem. I am on an embedded system with very little memory and want to minimize memory usage.
Pointers have always confused the heck out of me and will always do.

I have a whole bunch of defines for register addresses:

```
#define GPIO_PORTA_BASE      (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40004000))
#define GPIO_PORTB_BASE      (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40005000))
//etc..
```

These registers are direct accessible. e.g:

```
GPIO_PORT_BASE &= 0x01;
```

What I need is an array that contains the above registers so that I can easily map them to an index. e.g:

```
not_sure_what_to_declare_the array_as port_base_array[] {
   GPIO_PORTA_BASE,
   GPIO_PORTB_BASE,
   //etc
}
```

What I need to end up being able to do is something like this:

```
volatile unsigned long *reg;
*reg_a = port_base_array[0];
reg_a &=0x1;
```

I am using gcc to compile my code for arm cortex m3.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Comment: ... the question is pretty clear. He's trying to put `(*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40004000))` into an array. What's difficult to understand?

Comment: This is a side note: Before you start using `volatile`, read [this](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~regehr/papers/emsoft08-preprint.pdf) it shows that compiler optimizers don't handle volatile properly and it is potentially dangerous. It is [frowned upon](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/volatile-considered-harmful.txt) even in the linux kernel. And Dennis Ritchie himself [didn't like it](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/dmr-on-noalias.html) either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know why @Etienne deleted his answer, but it contained the essential information: The address is cast to `volatile unsigned long *`. That's what you need an array of.

```
typedef volatile unsigned long* reg_addr;

reg_addr registers[] = {
  &GPIO_PORTA_BASE,
  &GPIO_PORTB_BASE,
  // ...
};
```

We need to take the address again (`&GPIO_PORTA_BASE`), since the macro automatically dereferences them. Access as:

```
*registers[i] &= your_value;
```

Comment: @Xeo Eh, I wasn't sure it was an appropriate answer.

Comment: Xeo, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much for helping me out whit this! Did a quick test just now and it works like a charm! I am not entierly clear on what exactly is happening  but as I said, pointers are black magic to me and will probably alsways be. Know any good websites on this pointer magic? Not exacly clear on how much memory this array would take but I will post another question for this since it is out of scope here. Anyways, MANY thanks for helping me out with this. I burned quite some time on this while trying to figure this one out.

Answer (score 3):

Usual way is to declare a struct, for example :

```
struct RegsAtAddrA
{
  unsigned int array1[10];
  char val1;
  // etc
};
```

then to access it :

```
volatile RegsAtAddrA *pRegsA = (volatile RegsAtAddrA *) 0x40004000;
pRegsA->val1= 'a';
//etc
```

EDIT: I just realized that I haven't answered the question. So, here it is :

```
#include <iostream>
unsigned long a=1;
unsigned long b=2;
volatile unsigned long *port_base_array[] = {
   &a,
   &b,
   //etc
};
int main()
{
    std::cout<<"a="<<*port_base_array[0]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"b="<<*port_base_array[1]<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Your edit is wrong, since the macros are references, and already cast to the right type. Just take it's address again, see my answer. Or define them in another way I guess. :)

Comment: @Xeo It is not wrong. Anyway, here is fully compilable example that compiles with maximum warning level.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you're trying to do is something like this:

```
volatile unsigned long * gpio_porta = &GPIO_PORTA_BASE;
```

If you're using C++, you could also do the following:

```
volatile unsigned long & reg_foo = (&GPIO_PORTA_BASE)[3];
volatile unsigned long & reg_foo = gpio_porta[3];
```

And use it as:

```
reg_foo &= 0x1;
```

However, most times I would expect a base address register to actually be stored as a pointer, rather than as the dereference of the pointer. Because of that, I would probably want your macros to be defined as:

```
#define GPIO_PORTA_BASE      ((volatile unsigned long *) 0x40004000)
#define GPIO_PORTB_BASE      ((volatile unsigned long *) 0x40005000)
```

And then you could simply access them as

```
GPIO_PORTA_BASE[3] &= 0x1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting you right, this should be enough:

```
volatile unsigned long* GPIO_PORTA = (volatile unsigned long*) 0x40004000;
```

You could use that as

```
volatile unsigned long regxx = GPIO_PORTA[0x17];

// even

GPIO_PORTA[10] &= 0xF000;
```